# Is there a way to restrict characters generated by Bogus?

Tags: c#, faker, bogus

Our C# app has restrictions on certain string properties. For example, a city can't have apostrophes, among other values. When running my tests, I sometimes get false failures because Bogus generated a string with an invalid value. For now, I've added an extension method to filter out the offending characters. Is there a better way to do this?

I used fakers to generate test data. I expected no side effects, but I occasionally receive false test failures caused by the application's validation rules. Bogus is working as expected; I'm just exploring ways to handle the issue.